# goMap is only loading once

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

The user should be able to click on a link which will open a modal with a map inside. Everything works fine but when you close the modal and click on the link again the modal opens but the map doesn't load again.

This is the jQuery that opens the modal when the link is clicked.

```
$('.mapModal').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    var address = $('#doc' + id).data('ad');
    $("#map-modal").show();
    $("#modal-map").goMap({
        address: '' + address + ', South Africa',
        zoom: 20
    });
    $.goMap.createMarker({
        address: '' + address + ', South Africa'
    });
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $("#modal-map").html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete data(), so simply 
After $("#map-modal").show(); write

```
$("#map-modal").removeData();
$("#modal-map").goMap({
        address: '' + address + ', South Africa',
        zoom: 20
});
```

and you can lunch it again.

Answer (score 0):

goMap is using the jQuery `data()` method to add the data item "goMap" to your `#modal-map` element which makes it think there is still a map inside the element when you come to re-show the element. You would need to clear that data item out when you clear the html content of the element.

The alternative would be use the `hide()` method instead to hide the element and don't destroy the map content.